# Why "checked" attribute doesn't apply to my Thymeleaf's checkboxes?

Tags: spring, checkbox, thymeleaf, checked

I was working with Spring and Thymeleaf when I've encountered the following problem: I need a **Form** object, which has a list of items (**Item**) as attribute; I'm using an html form to print the Name of the Item, and to generate a checkbox for each Item (any checkbox's value is the corresponding item's id).

The form works correctly, sending to the Controller a list of item's ids corresponding to the checked checkboxes.

However, now, I'm trying to check some checkbox upon the occurrence of a condition (if itemIds, which is a list, contains the current item's id). For that I'm using:

```
th:checked="${#lists.contains(itemIds, item.id)}"/>
```

But it doesn't work (checkbox are all unchecked).
I tried also with a "dummy test":

```
th:checked="${1 == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}"/>
```

But, again, all the checkbox remain unchecked; the "checked" attribute is ignored as you can see in this example of the rendered HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="12" class="chkCheckBox" id="ids1" name="ids">
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

**form.html**

```
<form th:action="@{${uriBase}+'/new/' + ${date}}"
        method="POST" th:object="${form}">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th><input type="checkbox" th:id="checkAll"/>Check</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
                <td th:text="${item.name}"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{ids}"
                           th:value="${item.id}" th:class="chkCheckBox"
                           th:checked="${#lists.contains(itemIds, item.id)}"/>
                </td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Form class**

```
public class Form implements Serializable {

    private List<Long> ids;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this as well. If you use the `th:field` it will override the checked and value options, as Xaltotun mentions, because it is trying to get the value and checked option from the `field/form`.

If you change it to `th:name` it should work how you want...
But this [forum](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/The-checked-attribute-of-the-checkbox-is-not-set-in-th-each-td3043675.html) seems to be helpful for doing it with `th:feild`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there are 2 issues in your post:

1. The dummy example is incorrect.

   th:checked="${1 == 1 ? 'checked' : ''}"

In fact the value must true or false not 'checked'. If you try with

```
th:checked="${1 == 1}"/>
```

It will work.

2. If you set th:field="*{ids}" then the checkbox should be trying to get the value from the field **item.ids** and will not use the "th:checked" or "th:value" properties. Does the item has the field **ids**?